# Getting error while sending email using PHP and Angular.js

Tags: php, angularjs, email

I am getting the following error while sending email using `phpMailer` in PHP.

Error:

```
angularjs.js:93 POST http://localhost/crm/php/sendEmail.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am providing my code below.

sendEmail.php :

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$to=$request->to;
$url=$request->url;
$subject=$request->subject;
$msg=$request->message;
$image=$request->image;
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "********@gmail.com"; //Email that you setup
$mail->Password = "***********"; // Password
$mail->Subject=$subject;
$mail->Body=$message;
$mail->AddAddress("subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com"); //Recipient name is optional
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    $result["value"]=0;
    $result["msg"]=$mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    $result["value"]=1;
    $result["msg"]="Sent successfully";
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Please help us to help you. What's in the logs?

Comment: Its `500 Internal Server Error` that means you have an error within you PHP file

Comment: yes,but when i am removing/commenting  the line `$mail->AddAddress("subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com");`  this type of error is not coming but its throwing the error message `You must provide at least one recipient email address.`.

Comment: @Uchiha : I need to send email to `subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com` email id .Can you please make this correct.?

Comment: after adding $mail->from then what to do.

Comment: @Uchiha : I added `$mail->from` still the same error.

Comment: First of all you need to check what kind of logging the server spits out... Then post that logging here so we can help you further. If we don't know the error we cant help you..

Comment: here i am using `class.phpmailer.php` version `5.2.14` i think `addAddress` is not supported here.

Comment: You need to setup your environment in such a way that you have an full error message. Until you do this, it will take ages to resolve each error having just "500 Internal Server Error". Once you have the stack trace, it will be obvious where the error is.